# Can't get javascript to change img source

Tags: javascript, html

A real beginner here, with a really basic question, but I simply can't get Javascript to change pictures when using the build in "onclick()" with HTML images..

I looked through so many questions about this, and tried different approaches to changing it, but can't get it to work.

I've tried with different src's, providing the full path and with online image adresses. Tried passing the variable. Simply can't get it to work.

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title> Javascript - changing images </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      function change() {
        var image = document.getElementByID("fpimage");
        image.src = "logo2.png"
        
      }

   </script>
</head> 

   <body>
      <img src="logo.png" alt = "bla" id = "fpimage" onclick="change();"">
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`var image = document.getElementByID("fpimage");`

TO

`var image = document.getElementById("fpimage");`

Comment: Can't believe this... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled `getElementById` with a capital D

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title> Javascript - changing images </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      function change() {
        var image = document.getElementById("fpimage");
        image.src = "logo2.png"
        
      }

   </script>
</head> 

   <body>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cJjyJaG.jpg" alt = "bla" id = "fpimage" onclick="change();"">
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep, like Clyde said, you made a mistake on the **getElementById()** function, keep in mind that **Js is case sensitive** ;)

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title> Javascript - changing images </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      function change() {
        var image = document.getElementById("fpimage");
        image.src = "http://www.dinosoria.com/mammifere/paresseux-206.jpg"
        
      }

   </script>
</head> 

   <body>
      <img src="http://s.minutebuzz.com/i/2014/05/sloths-L.jpg.jpg" alt = "bla" id = "fpimage" onclick="change();"">
   </body>
   
</html>
```